# MySQL Limit 2 How to select second row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sMonOperationHours = "SELECT * FROM ".COMPANY_OPERATION_HOURS_TBL." WHERE 
f_company_id = '$g_companyid' AND f_day = 'MON' LIMIT 2";
$rsMonOperationHours = mysql_query($sMonOperationHours);
$rowMonOperationHours = mysql_fetch_array($rsMonOperationHours);
$iMonStartTime = $rowMonOperationHours['f_start_time'];
$iMonStartTime2 = ???;
$iMonEndTime = $rowMonOperationHours['f_end_time'];
$iMonEndTime2 = ???;
```

After limiting my SQL query result to 2, how do I select the f_start_time and f_end_time for the second row?

Comment: I think it is better to loop it just like how you do it most of the time..

Comment: To correctly limit any SQL query you must use a `order by` clause - otherwise the results can be "unexpected" (because tables are "unordered sets").

Answer (score 0):

You can use in LIMIT and OFFSET for getting the second result

```
$sMonOperationHours = "SELECT * FROM ".COMPANY_OPERATION_HOURS_TBL." WHERE 
f_company_id = '$g_companyid' AND f_day = 'MON' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1";
$rsMonOperationHours = mysql_query($sMonOperationHours);
$rowMonOperationHours = mysql_fetch_array($rsMonOperationHours);
$iMonStartTime = $rowMonOperationHours['f_start_time'];
$iMonEndTime = $rowMonOperationHours['f_end_time'];
```

Another way to do this, is if you want both of results, that is the way:

```
$sMonOperationHours = "SELECT * FROM ".COMPANY_OPERATION_HOURS_TBL." WHERE 
f_company_id = '$g_companyid' AND f_day = 'MON' LIMIT 2";
$rsMonOperationHours = mysql_query($sMonOperationHours);
$rowsData = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsMonOperationHours)) {
    $rowsData[$i] = array();
    $rowsData[$i][] =  $row['f_start_time'];
    $rowsData[$i][] =  $row['f_end_time'];
    $i++;
}
```

All data will be saved in rowsData which contains the results in array.